# Create new user without prompt with chpasswd

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to create a new user and associate directly a password (test pass) in a command line without be prompted. I get this error on Debian:

```
Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
Use of uninitialized value $answer in chop at /usr/sbin/adduser line 556.
Try again? [y/N] Use of uninitialized value $answer in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/adduser line 557.
```

I do that:

```
adduser --gecos "" plmadmin
echo testpass:testpass | chpasswd
adduser plmadmin sudo
```

Comment: `echo "somepassword" | passwd --stdin username`  should work since passwd has the `--stdin` flag.

Comment: @val0x00ff --stdin flag is not recognized by debian..

Comment: can you give an indicate if the answer solved your problem so it could help others as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little script and provide 2 arguments to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if (($# < 2));
  then
    printf 'Please provide the username and password\n'; exit 1
  else
    adduser "$1"
    printf "$1:%s" "$2" | chpasswd
  fi
```

1) Save the script in a file e.g addUsers  (no extension)

2) chmod u+x addUsers

3) ./addUsers username password

Answer (score 0):

```
   --disabled-password
   Like --disabled-login, but logins are still possible (for example using SSH RSA  keys)  but  not  using password authentication.

   -u, --unlock
       Unlock the password of the named account. This option re-enables a password by changing the password back to its previous value (to the value before using the -l option).


   adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" plmadmin
   echo -e "testpass\ntestpass\n" | passwd plmadmin
   passwd -u plmadmin
```

1. Disabled Password disables passworded login and you will not be prompted for a password.
2. The password is changed to what you set it as.
3. Passwords are enabled again for the account.